# What is the format for having an environmental object update from a picker selection in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, software-design, picker

I am trying to have a value chosen from a picker update a variable in the observable object class. However, the value does not seem to be binding. Does anyone have some example code for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69291549/13278922

Comment: If you show us some code maybe we can help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work to set the `EnvironmentObject` with the index of the picked object.

```
final class GlobalClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var itemIndex: Int
    init(){
        self.itemIndex = 0
    }
}

struct EnvironPicker: View{
    @EnvironmentObject private var globalObj: GlobalClass
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $globalObj.itemIndex, label:
                Text("Select")) {
                Text("No Action").tag(0)
                Text("Proposed").tag(1)
                Text("Sold").tag(2)
                Text("Lost").tag(3)
            }
            Text("PrintValue").onTapGesture {
                print(globalObj.itemIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a print to show the `globalObj.itemIndex` is updating with the binding.